# Constrain UIView's proportionally

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uilayoutguide

I want to position my view's in relative terms.  I want do use percentages and not pixels.  Say I want to position a button's center at 25% of its super view's height.  How would I do this?

One way to do it would be:

`button.topAnchor.constraint(
       equalTo: superView.topAnchor, 
       constant: /* compute constant "dynamically")
.isActive = true`

But this feels silly because we have a `multiplier` parameter in many of the Layout Margin API functions.

But yet if I type `button.centerYAnchor.constraint`, none of the suggested completions show any functions that take a `multiplier` argument except for one's with `systemSpacing` in the name.  I've looked into "system spacing" but cannot figure out what it does.

If I have this constraint:

`button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(rootView.topAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true`

The view is just position directly under its superView's top.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do it with the layout anchors, but here is how to do it by creating the `NSLayoutConstraint` directly:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY,
    relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .bottom,
    multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0).isActive = true
```